How does C++17 handle thread-safe initialization of inline static data members across multiple translation units?
I've been learning about inline static variables in C++17 and their initialization across multiple translation units. I understand that inline static variables are introduced to maintain a single instance across the program while ensuring thread-safe initialization. However, when you use inline static variables, the compiler seems to add a check to ensure that the variable is initialized in a thread-safe manner. This is necessary because the compiler cannot predict which translation unit will perform the initialization first, due to the inclusion of the header file in multiple translation units.
From what I've gathered, there seems to be some sort of guard mechanism (as seen in the assembly code linked below) that prevents multiple initializations.
So my questions are:
1)In each translation unit, is there a thread-safety guard for initialization during runtime?
2)After the variable is initialized, is it correct that no synchronization primitives are needed when it is accessed/used throughout the program?
https://godbolt.org/z/hhWoK7Y3r
#ifndef THING_H
#define THING_H
#include <string>
class Thing
{
public:
    inline const static std::string name{"Miko"};     
};
#endif // THING_H


Lookup "meyer's singleton".  static local variables in a function will be initialized in a threadsafe manner (since C++11).  I would not recommend having global variables (across TU's) anyway. Global variables are hell for maintainability of large code bases (closely followed by singletons). I recommend using dependency injection of "global" state. e.g. declare a struct, initialize it in main and pass it on to classes/functions that need information from it (use const if code is only supposed to read from global state)

The standard only describes what observable behaviour is required - it doesn't say how that behaviour is to be achieved.    The specifics for how it is achieved will be implementation (compiler, possibly library) specific.    One option would be based on Meyer's Singleton.

Depends on the complexity of initialization and initializer arguments. If the initialization can be done at compile-time, then it's just copied to the data segment of binary with ab solute 0 runtime costs; otherwise, if dynamic initialization is required, an equivalent of std::once_flag is associated with each inline global or function local static object. However, inline global objects should be less costly than function local static objects; because at the point of manipulation, they're known to have already been initialized; linker too can optimize the initialization test away.

Your question is currently unclear. Inline static variables can mean many different things (unfortunately). Please specify that you mean static member variables if that is indeed your intent.

@PepijnKramer: In this link: https://godbolt.org/z/hhWoK7Y3r, when the class 'Thing' with the 'inline' version is included in multiple source files, does it mean that each translation unit will have its own thread guard around that variable because the compiler cannot predict which translation unit will perform the initialization first? This question arises because with 'inline', multiple definitions are allowed, and the linker is responsible for de-duplication. Conversely, in the non-inline version, is there only one thread guard since there must be exactly one definition?

@PasserBy I provided the link in the question. I meant that type of inline variables.

No it will mean the linker will only pick one implementation inline promises that ALL instances of the function across all translation units will be the same (in C++ inline doesn't mean the compiler has to remove the call). The static local variable is initialized in a threadsafe manner and that is mandated by the C++ specification.

Even if the linked code is copied here, your prose still describes a broader question than you want, which is confusing. But either way, questions have to be self-contained and not rely on external links. Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information.

Notes: 1) Your text does not mention const, your code sample specifies const. 2) The initialization code shown in the linked generated assembly code is not called from main(). Presumably, it is called from the startup code before main is executed. Please correct me if I am wrong, but the guard mechanism appears to me to be to prevent multiple initiations from generated init routines called before main() from multiple translation units and doesn't appear to me to have any connection to thread safety.

@PepijnKramer For a non-inline const static data member, there's only one definition, and no thread-safe mechanism is needed due to a single initialization point. For an inline const static data member, despite appearing in multiple translation units, it's consolidated into one by the linker. However, since the compiler doesn't know which unit will initialize it first, so, a thread-guard is required to ensure that the initialization is thread-safe and happens exactly once across all translation units, similar to the approach used in the initialize-on-first-use idiom. Thanks& loved the DI tips!

@AviBerger
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7hwL0gHuP4&t=16s&ab_channel=C%2B%2BWeeklyWithJasonTurner

@Sam you're welcome. And for me DI (of abstract baseclasses or simple structs) is the only way to go in larger unit testable projects ;)

I watched the video. He does state thread safe. However, I can see nothing thread safe about the guard code shown in the video or in the godbolt link provided in the post.  The code in both places appears to me to be thread unsafe. Note that neither examples uses threads. Also, as long as the initialization is done by the startup code and no additional threads are started before main(), this is a non-issue. Now if you start a thread before main(), . . .

. . . I wonder if this would be a not quite static initialization order fiasco, but something similar? I don't know. Interesting. But I don't see any thread safe guard here, unless there is a critical section in code not shown. Also, all this is only about initialization, not later use.
